# Get a list of sales tabs using a URl or soql

Tags: soql, salesforcedx

What is the URL or SOQL code to get a list of Sales tabs shown in the image?

I tried the following URL.

```
https://ap2.salesforce.com/services/data/v31.0/tabs
```

But it shows all tabs, not only the Sales tabs.

[image: sales tab in salesforce]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I think SOQL is no help here as Tabs and TabSets are not available for queries.
This URI:
`https://ap2.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/appMenu/AppSwitcher`
Can you get a list of TabSets including the 'Sales' one but apart from navigating to the tab sets record page using its ID, there again isn't much you can do with this.

The Apex Schema class and `describeTabs()` method is the best way to get a list of Tabs for a given app programmatically I think (just as an FYI) but it seems you're looking for something strictly within SOQL and/or REST
Hope this Helps